# How to files form docker container to host in windows containers

Tags: windows, docker, continuous-integration, containers, microservices

I am learning docker. In my image build process i create a file called "appsettings.json" in a folder called "Config". I want this file to be editable by the user outside the container. The final goal is that a user can stop the container, make changes to the settings file and start the container again with the new settings file.

I am using windows containers on a windows 10 host. I created a new volume first:

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

After that I tried to start my container

```
docker run -v myvolume:C:/app/Config
```

However, it seems that the -v argument **deletes** all content in the Config folder. I was aware that bind mounts override folders in the container with folders on the host, but I thought this named volume will copy the appsettings file to the host.

What I could do is creating the volume first, starting the container and copying the file from within the container into the volume, but this seems to be an annoying overkill.

Is there any easier way or best practice to make files which result as part of the build process visible to the host file system?

Comment: I guess if you just mount windows path to container path like `docker run -v C:/pathonwindows:/pathoncontainer ` it works most of the time for me

Comment: no, this is not working, bind mounts create new folder in container this is as intended. But i thought it should work with named volumes.

Comment: You will need to populate the volume at start time with a script in this case. Docker doesn't copy any data automatically.

Comment: Are you sure the volume is fresh and has never been used by any other container? The behavior you described should be correct. (also, the Dockerfile you used may be handy)

Answer (score 2):

you can't mount files from your host machine into volumes. Like Pandey Amit already mentioned in the comments, you have to mount the Config directory of your host machine directly into the container. To achieve this in Windows 10, you have to grant the access to your filesystem in the docker settings first.

Open Docker Dashboard -> Settings -> Resources -> FILE SHARING + add here the directory, which should be mounted in your Docker containers (fyi: all the subdirectories are included)

I recommend to restart docker itself, to take note of the new settings.

Once docker has restarted, run your container:

`docker run -v C:/app/Config:/path/to/your/app/Config <image-name>`

This will mount the content of C:\app\Config into the container and now you should be able to modify the content of appsettings.json even without having to restart your container (but this depends on the architecture of your application -> if it supports a live reload of appsettings.json)

**UPDATE**: you cannot mount files from your docker image on a host machine. if you want, you could instruct the user to create the file manually on the host machine and follow with the steps described above. But if the only thing you want achieve, is to allow the user to override application settings I would recommend you to work with environment variables. For example run container with overwritten setting from the host machine:

`docker run -e "foo=bar" <image-name>`